# OpenVPN not working as expected

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am attempting to connect to another location using OpenVPN. I have been provided a script however once it runs through and says "Initialization Sequence Completed" I check my IP and it remains as is. The output is as follows:

```
Fri Jul 08 16:04:20 2016 NOTE: --group option is not implemented on Windows
Fri Jul 08 16:04:20 2016 NOTE: --user option is not implemented on Windows
Fri Jul 08 16:04:20 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.11 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on May 10 2016
Fri Jul 08 16:04:20 2016 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater) 64bit
Fri Jul 08 16:04:20 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.09
Fri Jul 08 16:04:20 2016 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth using INLINE static key file
Fri Jul 08 16:04:20 2016 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]103.240.178.197:21194 [nonblock]
Fri Jul 08 16:04:21 2016 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]103.240.178.197:21194
Fri Jul 08 16:04:21 2016 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Fri Jul 08 16:04:21 2016 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]???.???.???.???:?????
Fri Jul 08 16:04:21 2016 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Fri Jul 08 16:04:27 2016 [OpenVPN Server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]???.???.???.???:?????
Fri Jul 08 16:04:31 2016 Options error: --dhcp-option: unknown option type 'domain-name-servers' or missing parameter
Fri Jul 08 16:04:31 2016 Options error: --dhcp-option: unknown option type 'domain-name-servers' or missing parameter
Fri Jul 08 16:04:32 2016 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Fri Jul 08 16:04:32 2016 open_tun, tt->ipv6=0
Fri Jul 08 16:04:32 2016 TAP-WIN32 device [Ethernet] opened: ???.tap
Fri Jul 08 16:04:32 2016 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of ???.??.??.???(hidden for security reasons)/255.255.255.252 on interface {???-???-???-???} [DHCP-serv: ???.??.??.???, lease-time: 31536000]
Fri Jul 08 16:04:32 2016 Successful ARP Flush on interface [42] {???-???-???-???-????}
Fri Jul 08 16:04:34 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:34 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:34 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:35 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:36 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:36 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:36 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:36 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:36 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:36 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:36 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 16:04:36 2016 Initialization Sequence Completed
Fri Jul 08 16:05:54 2016 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Fri Jul 08 16:05:54 2016 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Fri Jul 08 16:05:59 2016 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]103.240.178.197:21194 [nonblock]
Fri Jul 08 16:06:00 2016 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]103.240.178.197:21194
Fri Jul 08 16:06:00 2016 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Fri Jul 08 16:06:00 2016 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]103.240.178.197:21194
Fri Jul 08 16:06:07 2016 [OpenVPN Server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]???.???.???.???:?????
Fri Jul 08 16:06:11 2016 Options error: --dhcp-option: unknown option type 'domain-name-servers' or missing parameter
Fri Jul 08 16:06:11 2016 Options error: --dhcp-option: unknown option type 'domain-name-servers' or missing parameter
Fri Jul 08 16:06:12 2016 Preserving previous TUN/TAP instance: Ethernet
Fri Jul 08 16:06:12 2016 Initialization Sequence Completed
Fri Jul 08 17:10:22 2016 TUN/TAP I/O operation aborted, restarting
Fri Jul 08 17:10:22 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
Fri Jul 08 17:10:23 2016 env_block: add PATH=C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem
```

How can i diagnose the problem? The fact that it runs env_block multiple times has me concerned but not too sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your log: `env_block` is an error message meaning that there is a problem with environment variables. More specifically, the variable PATH, which does not contain elements needed by OpenVPN. That means OpenVPN can't start the tools it needs to configure Windows correctly.

To check if that really is the problem:

1. Open Control Pannel
2. Go to System Properties
3. On the left, click Advanced System Parameters
4. Click Environment variables
5. Find "Path" in ne of the lists, slect it and click Modify
6. Check it to make sure there is `C:\windows\System32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem` in it
7. If there it or part of it is not there, add it. **Make sure whatever you add starts and ends with a semicolon.**

Note that `C:\windows` can be replaced by `%SystemRoot%` or `%windir%`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Checked environment variables and all three seem to be there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Make sur you run OpenVPN with elevated privileges (Right-click -> Run as Administrator or Properties -> Compatibility tab). Maybe it cannot start those programs because it lacks privileges.

Comment: Just noticed my logs say the following: "All TAP-Windows adapters on this system are currently in use." Apologies didnt know about this log.

Comment: Oops for you then ^^ and one more thing, next time you post logs like this, you should remove private data like password or *server IPs*. I know OpenVPN won't let anyone connect without the right certificates, but still...

Comment: Apologies. Thought i cleared the necessary but missed a bit.